# Changing Diagnostic Logging Level Works Incorrectly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, logging

We've changed the Diagnostic Logging levels to Critical and Trace Level to Unexpected.

[image]

Unfortunately, even after a week of doing it, I still get a flood of logs with Verbose and VerboseEx levels.

[image]

I did restart SharePoint Tracing Service, but it did nothing to change the problem.

I will be grateful for any suggestions!

**Update**

I tried resetting log levels to default both with PowerShell and Central Administration. Tried setting levels to None. Restarted Tracing Service half a dozen times. Nothing seems to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my other answer. Actually, the problem was with the Developer Dashboard. When you enable it, it enforces the VerboseEx logging. Problem solved. I had this exact problem on three SP2013 farms and two SP2010 farms.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead run:

`Clear-SPLogLevel`

This will re-set all categories to Medium. That said, there are instances where higher level verbosity is logged, but not in the manner your screenshot shows.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor. Unfortunately even all-powerful PowerShell can't help me with this. nothing seems to work

Comment: I was forced to turn Tracing Service off. Otherwise SharePoint logs eat up 2-4 GB every 20 minutes. Still thinking what to do. It seems like something is wrong with the entire farm. Maybe someone changed something in the registry or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the config cache (and then validating SPTimerV4 and the SharePoint Admin service are running)?

Comment: I've tried it today. It seemed to work at first. I did not see any log entries lower than medium level when playing in central administration website. However, when I've accessed the main site collection it just exploded with Verbose and VerboseEx messages. I had to stop the SharePoint Tracing service

Answer (score 0):

We've finally determined the culprit. **(Update: no, I didn't!) check my other answer**

It happens when we run the following command:

> PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent
>   -install -cmd installfeatures

When the upgrade process fails at about 10% - this annoying verbose problem appears.

We've checked it on 2 "healthy" farms and managed to replicated this problem.